# Why does R not return a value when using mode()?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I couldn't find the right answer to this after googling it but mode returned numeric and I'm not sure how to make it return a number?

```
MoneyData<-c(42000,63000,32000,22000,22000,22000,32000,52000,63000,92000,86000,72000,46000,12000,76000,44000,38000,148000,79000,24000,18000,80000,62000,37000,42000,89000,102000,78000,90000)

mode(MoneyData)

output : > mode(MoneyData)
         [1] "numeric"
```

I tried googling how to make it return a value instead of "numeric" but everything said that it would only return a number so how am I getting this?

Comment: It says, Error in getmode(MoneyData) : could not find function "getmode"

Comment: Your question is answered by the link we have provided. Also, please do not use the Rstudio tag unless it is specifically about the IDE. Your question is specific to R.

Comment: The link you posted does not answer my question, my friend is right next to me doing mode(Dataset) and they get a return value of 14 which is the median for their data set

Comment: That would happen if they created or ran a custom function called `mode` (i.e. `mode <- function(x) { ... }`) prior to executing the line. R will then use the custom function instead of the default version.

Comment: R has a function called [`mode()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/mode.html) which returns the storage mode of an object. In your case you may want to use the the function `Mode()` of the package `DescTools`. (either load the library or use `DescTools::Mode(MoneyData)`

Comment: Im still a little confused cause all my friend and professor did was mode(Dataset) and it returned their variable they didnt have to implement all the other stuff but I will try and figure it out with all the help you have given me thank you!

Comment: They must have loaded a package that defined a `mode()` function. The behavior you described does not match the default behavior of R. Check to see what `library()` calls they made prior to calling that function. Or perhaps they are running in a non-standard R environment.